# Search Data in continuous form in MS Access

Tags: sql-server

I have a continuous form in MS Access 2003. The source data is a SQL Server link table. I display all the data by the SQL Server table and under the data I have text boxes to search in the above fields (of the form). I have made a routine for dynamic search which I call from the `after_update` event of the text box. Previously when I had the data in the MS Access backend it was working properly but now that I moved the data from MS Access backend to SQL Server table (backend) it does not work properly when I hit enter and I can't make my search. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: "it does not work properly" what does this mean? Does the search re-query the database or filter it locally? Are you getting errors? How far does it get? Given we don't have access to your system we need a lot more information to assist you find the cause of the issue. You need to investigate all possibilities and explain in more detail how your system works.

Comment: The problem here is that you haven't actually asked a question. You see nobody has any clue about your Access form or your sql table or what the actual issue is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My Routine dynamic search:

```
Private Function DynamicSearch(ctl As CONTROL)
On Error Resume Next
Dim strfilter As String
Dim LikeMember As String

If Len(ctl.Text) > 0 Then
    SendKeys ("{F2}")
    strfilter = ctl.Text
    LikeMember = Replace(ctl.Name, "Search", vbNullString)
    If Len(Me.FILTER) > 0 Then
        Me.FILTER = Me.FILTER & " AND " & LikeMember & "  like '*" & strfilter & "*'"
    Else
        Me.FILTER = LikeMember & "  like '*" & strfilter & "*'"
    End If
    Me.FilterOn = True
Else
    If Me.FilterOn Then
        Me.FilterOn = False
        ctl.SetFocus
        SendKeys ("{F2}")
    End If
End If
```

End Function

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are doing here?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).